# Select nested elements regardless of location

Tags: html, css

I want to select all item's with *.demo-img* style in all sub tags of the *.demo-container*. In my application I don't know the structure of the *.demo-container*.

```
.demo-container > .demo-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: width height 400ms ease-out;
}

.demo-container:hover > .demo-img {
    width: 102%;
    height: 102%;
}

<div class="demo-container">
    <div>
        <img class="demo-img" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img class="demo-img" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.demo-container{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
}
.demo-container .demo-img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: width height 400ms ease-out;
    background-color: red;
}

.demo-container:hover .demo-img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo-container">
    <div>
        <img class="demo-img" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img class="demo-img" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just use class

Comment: I can't just use class because I need to apply a transition on the img's within the "main" div, without knowing the structure inside "main" on main:hover

Comment: I've updated the post with a more accurate code example

Comment: @TheRuler Remove '>' selector.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Young Kyun Jin's answer, you can also select it without the class:

```
.main img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```